# Passing request from domain to view

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am working on a WPF application in which a user may initiate a process by pushing a button on the UI. The user may then be prompted with a sequence of actions that they must carry out to complete the process. The view is responsible for passing the initial request to initiate the process down to the domain. The view is also responsible for DISPLAYING the steps that the user must perform to complete the process.
The domain, on the other hand, is squarely response for working out WHAT steps must be carried out by the user. The domain is also capable of detecting when a user has completed the requested step.

If a user initiates a process, and that process requires them to perform some physical action, then I would like a box to pop-up with a message describing what they must do. When the action has been completed, it is detected by the domain, and the window should automatically close.

Passing requests from the View down to the Domain is simple. I do this using the wpf ICommand pattern. It is passing information back the other way that I am finding challenging. I am aware of bindings and the INotifyProperyChanged interface, but I do not feel that this is a good fit for what I am trying to do.

So, here is my initial attempt...

This interface is implemented by the View and consumed by the Domain. It allows the domain to communicate with the user;

```
public interface IUserRequestMedium
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ask the user to perform an action. User does
    /// not need to provide any feedback via the user
    /// interface, since it is possible for the 
    /// application to detect when the action has been
    /// carried out by the user. The dialog will be closed
    /// when either the requested action has been detected,
    /// or the user aborts.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">
    /// Request to be displayed to the user.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="userAbortCallback">
    /// Callback invoked by the view when the user cancels
    /// the request.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="actionDetectedCallback">
    /// Callback invoked by the domain to confirm the 
    /// that the requested action has been completed.
    /// </param>
    void AskUserToPerformDetectableAction(
        string message, Action userAbortCallback,
        out Action actionDetectedCallback);
}
```

Here is the View code-behind. Some of this code was taken from tutorials (and subsequently mangled) on the web. It's not working, but I hopefully it communicates my intent.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IUserRequestMedium
{
    // Constructor and other stuff...

    public void AskUserToPerformDetectableAction(
        string message, Action userAbortCallback,
        out Action actionDetectedCallback)
    {
        Action closeWindow;
        NewWindowThread(
            () => new ActionRequestBox(message, userAbortCallback),
            out closeWindow);

        actionDetectedCallback = closeWindow;
}

    private Window newWindow;

    private void NewWindowThread(
        Func<Window> construction,
        out Action closeWindow)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            newWindow = construction();
            newWindow.Show();
            newWindow.Closed += (sender, e) => newWindow.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();

        Window rememberedWindow = newWindow;
        closeWindow = () =>
        {
            if (rememberedWindow != null)
                rememberedWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action(Close));
        };
    }
}
```

And here's a usage example from the domain;

```
public class SomeDomainClass
{
    IUserRequestMedium userRequestMedium; // assume this has been assigned in constructor

    private Action notifyUserOfActionDetected;

    public void PerformSomeProcess()
    {
        bool processCannotBeCompletedWithoutPowerCycle = ...; // some logic
        if (processCannotBeCompletedWithoutPowerCycle)
        {
            userRequestMedium.AskUserToPerformDetectableAction(
                "Please cycle the power on the external device",
                CancelProcess,
                out notifyUserOfActionDetected);
        }
    }

    public void CancelProcess()
    {
        // User doesn't want to perform the required action
        // so process must be aborted...
    }

    private void OnPowerCycleDetected()
    {
        notifyUserOfActionDetected();
    }
}
```

How can I make this work? It is the cross-threading aspect that I am getting caught on. I have not been successful in making the window automatically close when the action is detected by the domain.

Or, taking a step backward, is there a better approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After learning a little about Dispatcher.Invoke, this is what I ended up with. So far it seems to be working pretty well.

```
    private Window activeRequestBox;

    // invoked on domain thread
    public void AskUserToPerformDetectableAction(
        string message, Action userAbortCallback,
        out Action actionDetectedCallback)
    {
        OpenDetectableActionRequestBox(message, userAbortCallback);
        actionDetectedCallback = CloseRequestBox;
    }

    private void OpenDetectableActionRequestBox(
        string message, Action userAbortCallback)
    {
        Action openWindow =
            () =>
            {
                activeRequestBox = new DetectableActionRequestBox(
                     message, userAbortCallback);
                activeRequestBox.Closed += RequestBoxClosedHandler;
                activeRequestBox.Show();
            };
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(openWindow);            
    }


    // invoked on request box thread
    private void RequestBoxClosedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        activeRequestBox = null;
    }

    // invoked on domain thread
    private void CloseRequestBox()
    {
        if (activeRequestBox != null)
        {
            Action closeWindow =
                () => activeRequestBox.Close();
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(closeWindow);
        }
    }
```